# Having trouble figuring out how to best structure my database. Any direction or advice would be helpful

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, postgresql, data-structures

Relative newbie here. I am building an app that displays lineups from different soccer games. I have seeded the database through a remote API that has all of the data that I need for matches (which teams played, what was the score), players (the roster of each team), and teams (names, logos, schedule) and they're all associated appropriately.

Now, I'm trying to navigate building line-ups for each match. I need the app to recognize the players participating in each match as their own separate events.

I would like each match to have 2 line-ups (the line-ups all have a match_id that can be seeded from the API I'm using), and for those lineups to have all participating players (again, data that is available through the API).

Where I'm getting tripped up is should the lineup be its own separate thing that has_many players, or should it go through the team's matches? I'm new to structuring a database and this is my first real bump in the road so sorry if the answer feels self-explanatory.

Here are my models and schema file. Maybe I'm overthinking it.

```
class Team < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :players
  has_many :home_matches, :foreign_key => :home_team_id, :class_name => "Match"
  has_many :away_matches, :foreign_key => :away_team_id, :class_name => "Match"
  **has_many :lineups** 

  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: :history
end
```

```
class Lineup < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :team
  belongs_to :match
  has_many :players, :through => :lineup_players
end
```

```
class Player < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :team
    has_many :ratings
    has_and_belongs_to_many :lineups, :through => :lineup_players
end
```

```
class LineupPlayer < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :players, :through => :teams
  belongs_to :lineup
end
```

```
class Match < ApplicationRecord
  require 'rest-client'
  belongs_to :home_team, :class_name => 'Team'
  belongs_to :away_team, :class_name => 'Team'
  **has_many :lineups**
end
```

Here is what my schema currently looks like...

```
  create_table "lineups", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "match_id"
    t.integer "player_id"
    t.integer "team_id"
  end

  create_table "lineup_players", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "lineup_id"
    t.text "player_id"
  end

  create_table "matches", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "datetime", precision: nil
    t.integer "home_team_score"
    t.integer "away_team_score"
    t.integer "home_team_id"
    t.integer "away_team_id"
  end

  create_table "players", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.integer "team_id"
    t.string "slug"
    t.index ["slug"], name: "index_players_on_slug", unique: true
  end

  create_table "teams", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.text "logo"
    t.string "slug"
    t.index ["slug"], name: "index_teams_on_slug", unique: true
  end
```

Comment: Tip: Don't put in emphasis in your code that is also syntax. The `**` stuff is distracting. If you need to add remarks, please, *use comments*.

Comment: Tip: It's 2022 and Ruby 1.8 is long dead. You can use the `foreign_key: :home_team_away` notation that is syntactically a lot more in line with JavaScript, Python, etc.

Comment: Tip: `t.belongs_to` instead of just some random `x_id` field. This will also add an index, and force `NOT NULL` by default, which can avoid a lot of referencing errors.

Comment: The `matches` table is a little irregular. A `match_participant` table with a field set to `home`/`away` might be better if you care about quickly pulling all scores for a particular team. This is a subjective call though.

Comment: What are your use cases? They should inform the shape of the data , and without them, any advice could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need a join table or [a has and belongs to many](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association) relationship between players and line ups here.

That will allow line ups to have many players and players to belong to many line ups. Your schema would then be something like:

```
  create_table "lineups", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "match_id"
    t.integer "team_id"
  end

  create_table "lineup_players", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "lineup_id"
    t.integer "player_id"
  end
```

Comment: Trying this now. Updated my models and schema in the original post. How does that look?